# Splines in integer arithmetic?

Tags: c, algorithm, numerical-methods, fixed-point, splines

Splines (the piecewise cubic polynomial form) can be written as:

```
s = x - x[k]
y = y[k] + a[k]*s + b[k]*s*s + c[k]*s*s*s
```

where `x[k] < x < x[k+1]`, the curve passes through each `(x[k], y[k])` point, and a,b,c are arrays of coefficients describing the slope and shape.  This all works fine in floating point, and there are plenty of ways to calculate a,b,c for different kinds of splines.  However...

How can this be approximated in integer arithmetic?

One of the tricky parts is that any approximation should, ideally, be continuous, in other words using `x=x[k+1]` and the coefficients from the k-th segment, the result should be `y[k+1]` except for rounding errors.  In other words, for a straight segment, `y[k+1] == y[k] + a[k]*(x[k+1] - x[k])`, and curvy segments only deviate from this in the middle but not at either end.  This is guaranteed by construction in the case of floating point, but even a small coefficient change from rounding can throw it off quite a bit.

Another tricky part is that, in general, the magnitude of the higher-order coefficients is much smaller - but not always, esp. not at sharp "corners".  It may still make sense to scale them up by the typical size of s to the power of whatever order they are, so they are not rounded of to zero as integers, but that would seem to trade off resolution in curvature for max possible corner sharpness.

First try at an integer version:

```
y = y[k] + (a[k] + (b[k] + c[k]*s)*s)*s
```

Then use integer multiply (intended for 16bit values, 32bit arithmetic):

```
#define q (1<<16)
#define mult(x, y) ((x * y) / q)

y = y[k] + mult(mult(mult(c[k], s) + b[k], s) + a[k], s)
```

This looks good in theory, but I'm not sure it's the best possible approach, or how to tell systematically what the best possible approach is.

Comment: I would use fixed point ... but as you suggested the dynamic range of coefficients can be a problem why do you want avoid floats? (absence of FPU on target platform?) with FPU present the operation on float and integers are not that different in speed on current common HW

Comment: @Spektre: Yes no FPU and no native 32bit; there is a 16x16->32bit multiplier.  Fixed point is interesting but how would you do that in this case?  Assume something like libfixmath is available :)

Comment: you do not need any libs just correct result by bit shift after any multiplication. the bit counts depends on the range of your control points and desired target precision